# AVR128DB28 USART bootloader page

Tags: avr

I have a problem writing data to flash memory. If I use `int main`, programming runs normally, but if I use `__attribute__((naked)) __attribute__((section(".ctors"))) void boot(void)`, programming can't write to address memory I want to page.

```c
#include "libcomp.h"

const flash_adr_t address = 0x1fc00;

#ifndef MAIN_TEST
/*
 * Main boot function
 * It represents the enter point for the device to start execution
 * It represents the enter point for the device to start execution
 * Naked attribute instructs the compiler to omit the function prologue and epilogue
 */
  __attribute__((naked)) __attribute__((section(".ctors"))) void boot(void)
#else
int main(void)
#endif
{
    int value;
    /* Initialize system for AVR GCC support, expects r1 = 0 */
    asm volatile("clr r1");
    SYSTEM_Initialize();
    
    uint8_t buffer[PROGMEM_PAGE_SIZE];
    uint8_t data_flash[PROGMEM_PAGE_SIZE] = "Main boot function. It represents the enter point for the device to start execution.";
    
    value = strlen((char)data_flash);
    FLASH_WriteFlashPage(address, data_flash);
    
    _delay_ms(500); 
    BLD_Init();
    uint16_t i = 0;
    
    while (1)
    {
        if (USART0_IsTxReady()) {
            for (int k = 0; k < value; k++) {
                USART0_Write(FLASH_ReadFlashByte(address + k));
            }
            USART0_Write('\n');
        }
    
        ClrWdt();
        BLD_Tasks();
        
        if (++i == 0)
            LED3_Toggle();
    }

#ifdef MAIN_TEST
return 0;
#endif
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I use `__attribute__((naked)) __attribute__((section(".ctors"))) void boot(void)`

These attributes make no sense. Section `.ctors` contains **addresses of static constructors**; it does not contain executable code.

> `asm volatile("clr r1");`

This is hack and might not work as you expect. Avoid it or move it to the assembly part of your startup code.

---

If you need custom start-up code, you can use

## Static Constructors

This feature is specific to GCC. The syntax is like

```cpp
__attribute__((__constructor__))
static void init (void)
{
    // C/C++ code
}
```

Notice that the `static` in the code limits visibility of the constructor, it has nothing to do with the constructor being static. The generated code will be something like:

```
.global __do_global_ctors
.section .ctors,"a",@progbits
.p2align    1
.word   gs(init)
```

`__do_global_ctors` will traverse `.ctors` and call the static constructors. It lives in libgcc and avr-gcc references it so it is dragged from libgcc.

## Naked Code in `.init` Sections

This feature is specfic to avr-gcc. The syntax is like

```cpp
__attribute__((__used__,__unused__,__naked__,__section__(".init8")))
static void init8 (void)
{
  __asm volatile ("; code");
}
```

- Only (inline) assembly is supported in naked functions.
- If some `.initN` section contains more than one function, the order of execution is unspecified.

The following sections have library resp. start-up code located / attached to to them:

- `.init0`: Implements vector0: Set up `__zero_reg__`, `SP`, `EIND`, and `RAMP*` registers (from AVR-LibC).
- `.init4`: Run `__do_copy_data` and `__do_clear_bss` as needed (from libgcc).
- `.init6`: Run `__do_global_ctors` as needed (from libgcc).
- `.init9`: Call `main` and `exit` (from AVR-LibC).

## Own Startup Code

If you prefer own startup code altogether, then

- Write that code as (inline) assembly.
- Link with `-nostartfiles`.
- Define the following symbols as empty: `__do_copy_data`, `__do_clear_bss`, `__do_global_ctors`.
- The vector table is part of AVR-LibC's startup code, hence with `-nostartfiles` you'll have to provide your own vectab.

Comment: Thank to your answer

Comment: I has a question about bootloader USART on AVR. I configurate as the document of microchip but it still not run. I don't understand 2 point configuration as addition and flash segment with function -Wl,-section-start=.text=0x200

Comment: You can open a new question and add a *reproducible* example. In the code above, nothing is known about all the functions or macros you are using, and "does not run" is quite unspecific.